# Extrude Individual Not Working

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude the faces of a part along it's normals but it's not working. In edit mode in the tools panel I click Extrude Individual but the faces don't move in the right direction. I've tried extruding and right-clicking to make extra faces then moving those faces about their individual origins with the normals coordinate system turned on but that doesn't work. I made another part which is just a simple cylinder and extruding individuals works fine on that one. Maybe there is something wrong with my mesh.
[image: Trying to extrude the top.]

Blend file: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> `Scale`) for target model.

[image]

See also: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)